# gnome-keyring can't clear passphrase

Tags: pgp, gnome-keyring

Under Ubuntu 18.04, gnome-keyring caches PGP passphrases and will retain them, even through logout or reboot. I'm using the program `pass` to retain my passwords, so I want to be challenged every time I ask pass to show me a password. However, since gnome-keyring retains the password, anyone at my machine can view all of my passwords.

- I used `dconf-editor` to change the gpg-cache-method to "timeout" and the `gpg-cache-ttl` to 1 second. Then I reset the gnome-keyring daemon with: `$ gnome-keyring-daemon -r`

However, upon using the passphrase again, it gets cached and will not request the passphrase.

Why is gnome-keyring not honoring these settings? How can I fix this? This is extremely insecure.

Comment: Previously, I was able to launch a separate instance of `gpg-agent` for `pass`, but an OS upgrade now got me a version of GnuPG that I haven’t figured out yet – it wouldn’t honour `GPG_AGENT_INFO`, and `gpg-agent` discovers the other running agent by some other means and wouldn’t launch. Following.

Comment: FWIW, I’ve discovered that in my case (Cinnamon desktop installed over Ubuntu 18.04) the actual agent used by GPG is the one started by systemd for the user session. You can verify that by comparing the output of `gpgconf --list-dirs agent-socket` against the output of `systemctl --user status gpg-agent.socket`. If this is your case, then you can configure this agent by writing a `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf` file.